# Writing Content Under Script Tags

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create script tags dynamically under my page using javascript.  So far I am able to create it, able to set its type and src.  Now my question is, is there any way that instead of defining the src to a different page can I assign its content on the same page?  Let me write my code to make it make more sense:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = 'custom.js';
```

Now is there any way I can assign it the content as well by doing something like this:

```
script.content = 'document.write("stackoverflow")';
script.html = 'document.write("stackoverflow")';
```

I am not sure whether they exist or not, but just guessing if i can do something like this.

Comment: Can you explain WHAT you are trying to achieve instead of how you think you might achieve it? Writing dynamic script does not make any sense so far. Also you would not want to use document.write after page load since it wipes the page you are on

Comment: @mplungjan i know it will wipe the entire page off, i am testing something , so explaining the entire story will not make sense coz everything else works fine and i am just looking for a way where i can assign content under script tag in a dynamic way

Comment: Assigning to `script.text` should do the trick—of course what you assign must be a valid program.

Comment: jsFiddle is down so I cannot test anything quickly :(

Comment: yup same here... jsfiddle is down.. and i will try what robG said,

Answer (score 61):

You can do:

```
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.type = 'text/javascript';
script_tag.text = 'alert("hello world")';
document.body.appendChild(script_tag);
```

In practice, whether you set the type property or not is likely irrelevant, but it gives one a warm inner glow.

Comment: works fine when i am doing with pure javascript but not working with jquery ... saying $ not defined though i have included a copy of jquery :-(

Comment: If you're inserting script that requires jQuery, you need to make sure it's loaded first.

Answer (score 4):

Scripts can be read from or written to using 'scripts.text'. It's part of the script Data Object Model (DOM). And for some reason or another, it is different than other HTML tags. Example: 'myScript.innerHTML' tends not to work, but 'scripts.namedItem("myScript").text' does.

```html
<p>Change scripts.text <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_script_text.asp">https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_script_text.asp</a>
</p>

<p>Script Object <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_script.asp">https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_script.asp</a>
</p>

<canvas id="Canvas1" style="border: 5px solid cyan"></canvas>
<p id="Para1">...</p>
<button onclick="ChangeScript()">Change Script</button>
<button onclick="DrawIt()">Drawit</button>
<button onclick="para1.innerHTML=script1.text;">Show Script</button>


<script id="Script1"></script>

<script>
  function ChangeScript() {
    script1.text = "function DrawIt(){canvas1.fillRect(1,2,30,40)}"
  }

  //Note: changing the script text more than once may not work.

  canvas1 = document.getElementById("Canvas1").getContext("2d");
  script1 = document.scripts.namedItem("Script1");
  para1 = document.getElementById("Para1")
</script>



<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FCR1ZI3MBN77">Try it Yourself, Change scripts.text</a>
```

Comment: Explain your answer